# How to randomly select a card from a deck of cards and not select it again?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, playing-cards

I am trying to build a game based on random card selection. The player draws a card, once the card has been drawn the card will not be drawn again.

I've tried to make it work but I'm getting an error on my website saying "Uncaught TypeError: currentCard.filter is not a function"

Here is my code:

```
    cards = [
    'clubs-ace',
    'clubs-2',
    'clubs-3',
    'clubs-4',
    'clubs-5',
    'clubs-6',
    'clubs-7',
    'clubs-8',
    'clubs-9',
    'clubs-10',
    'clubs-jack',
    'clubs-queen',
    'clubs-king',
    'diamonds-ace',
    'diamonds-2',
    'diamonds-3',
    'diamonds-4',
    'diamonds-5',
    'diamonds-6',
    'diamonds-7',
    'diamonds-8',
    'diamonds-9',
    'diamonds-10',
    'diamonds-jack',
    'diamonds-queen',
    'diamonds-king',
    'hearts-ace',
    'hearts-2',
    'hearts-3',
    'hearts-4',
    'hearts-5',
    'hearts-6',
    'hearts-7',
    'hearts-8',
    'hearts-9',
    'hearts-10',
    'hearts-jack',
    'hearts-queen',
    'hearts-king',
    'spades-ace',
    'spades-2',
    'spades-3',
    'spades-4',
    'spades-5',
    'spades-6',
    'spades-7',
    'spades-8',
    'spades-9',
    'spades-10',
    'spades-jack',
    'spades-queen',
    'spades-king'
];

var currentCard = "";
var kingsCup = 0;

function drawCard() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (currentCard.length));
    currentCard = currentCard.filter((e, i) => i !== randomNumber);
    console.log(currentCard.length);

    switch(currentCard[randomNumber]) {
        case 1:
           document.getElementById("cards").src="assets/js/games/cards/clubs-ace.png";
        break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("cards").src="assets/js/games/cards/clubs-2.png";
        break;
        case 3:
            document.getElementById("cards").src="assets/js/games/cards/clubs-3.png";
        break;
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("cards").src="assets/js/games/cards/clubs-4.png";
        break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("cards").src="assets/js/games/cards/clubs-5.png";
        break;
        case 6:
            document.getElementById("cards").src="assets/js/games/cards/clubs-6.png";
        break;
        case 7:
            document.getElementById("cards").src="assets/js/games/cards/clubs-7.png";
        break;
        case 8:
            document.getElementById("cards").src="assets/js/games/cards/clubs-8.png";
        break;
        case 9:
            document.getElementById("cards").src="assets/js/games/cards/clubs-9.png";
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner at JS and the code could probably be written in a neater and more efficient way, so please excuse the long, messy code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure if you want to only select one card or multiple cards and show them on HTML is that what you're after?

Comment: One card at a time. It'll show on HTML. And then the user will click the button again and it will display another random card which will not be a card that has already been picked.

Comment: Cool... Then my solution is right, Can you try it again. I've basically changed the entire workaround... I realized that slice won't work well because of the random number... So I had to use loops so that I can be able to compare the positions of each card with the randomNumber created...

Comment: I've just given  you my last chance... The way you've create your html wasn't gonna work. You are not supposed to be changing the src everytime. But you must actually create a new img for each card created. I've illustrated this using <span> with card name as an example on my answer below. I'll leave it here for you to decide.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically responding to:

> I'm a beginner at JS and the code could probably be written in a
>   neater and more efficient way, so please excuse the long, messy code.

As a general rule, you want to try and separate your data and logic, but your code mixes both.

Consider instead something like:

```
const cardsById = {
    1: 'clubs-ace'
    2: 'clubs-2'
    // ...
};


document.getElementById("cards").src =
  'assets/js/games/cards/' + cardsById[randomNumber]+ '.png';
```

That way you have your data (`cardsById`) with just the unique data parts (the image names and IDs), and the logic is separate.

As for not picking the same card twice, one option would be to remove each card as you pick it using `slice` as @Crayon Violent suggested in the comments (although I'd recommend `splice`, with a "p", instead for that).

Another would be to add each card's ID to a second `alreadyPicked` array, and then check that array when you generate a random ID; if it's one you already picked, re-pick.  Which style is better depends on your specific code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like this... Keep two lists handy that handles the cards. The first list stores the entire cards and the second one stores the `currentCards` list. So every time you draw a card from the main list `cards`, it is added to the `currentCards` and removed from the main `cards`, so you will never repeat the same card. The `randomNumber` will be updated as the list of `cards` list gets smaller as well.

```js
var drawnCardsDisplay = document.getElementById('drawnCards');
var cards = [
    'clubs-ace',
    'clubs-2',
    'clubs-3',
    'clubs-4',
    'clubs-5',
    'clubs-6',
    'clubs-7',
    'clubs-8',
    'clubs-9',
    'clubs-10',
    'clubs-jack',
    'clubs-queen',
    'clubs-king',
    'diamonds-ace',
    'diamonds-2',
    'diamonds-3',
    'diamonds-4',
    'diamonds-5',
    'diamonds-6',
    'diamonds-7',
    'diamonds-8',
    'diamonds-9',
    'diamonds-10',
    'diamonds-jack',
    'diamonds-queen',
    'diamonds-king',
    'hearts-ace',
    'hearts-2',
    'hearts-3',
    'hearts-4',
    'hearts-5',
    'hearts-6',
    'hearts-7',
    'hearts-8',
    'hearts-9',
    'hearts-10',
    'hearts-jack',
    'hearts-queen',
    'hearts-king',
    'spades-ace',
    'spades-2',
    'spades-3',
    'spades-4',
    'spades-5',
    'spades-6',
    'spades-7',
    'spades-8',
    'spades-9',
    'spades-10',
    'spades-jack',
    'spades-queen',
    'spades-king'
];

var currentCards = [];

function drawCard() {
    // ue cards here instead of currentCards
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cards.length - 1));
    
    currentCards.push(
      // Run an immediately self executing function expression
      (function(){
        // store the elected card temorarily
        var tempSelectedCard = cards[randomNumber];
        // Remove that card from the main cards
        cards = getUnDrawnCards(randomNumber);
        // return the selected card and store it inside the currentCards array
        return tempSelectedCard;
      })()
    );
    // After Drawing the card, display it.
    showDrawnCards(currentCards);
}

function getUnDrawnCards(cardPositionToBeRemoved) // returns card[]
{
  if(cardPositionToBeRemoved)
  {
    // create a temporary array storage
    var tempNewCards = [];
    
    // Loop through the cards
    cards.forEach(function(card, index)
    {
      // if the card to be removed does matches the current card position
      if(index !== cardPositionToBeRemoved)
      {
        // Add it to the tempArrayList
        tempNewCards.push(cards[index]);
      }
      // At tis poist the matched index will not be part of the cards anymore
    });
    
    // Return tempNewCards
    return tempNewCards;
  }
  return [];
}

function showDrawnCards(drawnCardsArray)
{
  if(drawnCardsArray.length > 0)
  {
    drawnCardsDisplay.innerHTML = '';
    drawnCardsArray.map(function(card)
    {
      var drawn_card = document.createElement('span');
      drawn_card.innerHTML = card;
      drawnCardsDisplay.appendChild(drawn_card);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
span{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border: thin solid #dbdbdb;
  margin: 5px;
}
button{
margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="drawnCards"></div>
<button onClick="drawCard()">Click to Draw</button>
```

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot Read Property 'NaN' of undefined" error when I try this :(

Comment: Let me check it quickly, it was working before I submitted the answer.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry it was the variable tempSelectedCard... I had changed it just before I submitted as I was writing my comments. You can run it now.

Comment: SO basically this just calls the draw method 3 times and select numbers three times and display them on console... but the whole idea is that the selected cards cannot possibly be selected again.

Answer (score 0):

i believe this should work.

```js
const selectableCards = [
    'clubs-ace',
    'clubs-2',
    'clubs-3',
    'clubs-4',
    'clubs-5',
    'clubs-6',
    'clubs-7',
    'clubs-8',
    'clubs-9',
    'clubs-10',
    'clubs-jack',
    'clubs-queen',
    'clubs-king',
    'diamonds-ace',
    'diamonds-2',
    'diamonds-3',
    'diamonds-4',
    'diamonds-5',
    'diamonds-6',
    'diamonds-7',
    'diamonds-8',
    'diamonds-9',
    'diamonds-10',
    'diamonds-jack',
    'diamonds-queen',
    'diamonds-king',
    'hearts-ace',
    'hearts-2',
    'hearts-3',
    'hearts-4',
    'hearts-5',
    'hearts-6',
    'hearts-7',
    'hearts-8',
    'hearts-9',
    'hearts-10',
    'hearts-jack',
    'hearts-queen',
    'hearts-king',
    'spades-ace',
    'spades-2',
    'spades-3',
    'spades-4',
    'spades-5',
    'spades-6',
    'spades-7',
    'spades-8',
    'spades-9',
    'spades-10',
    'spades-jack',
    'spades-queen',
    'spades-king'
]

const currentCard = {}
const cardsAlreadySelected = []
const kingsCup = 0

const drawCard = () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (selectableCards.length))
  const currentCard = selectableCards.splice(randomNumber, 1)
  console.log(currentCard.length)
  document.getElementById("cards").src = `assets/js/games/cards/${currentCard}.png`
}
```